# Прогресс выполнения запроса к серверу

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-asynctask

Вывожу progress-bar при отправке данных на сервер. Смотрится хорошо если запрос занимает время, но если запрос выполняется мгновенно прогресс просто мелькает.
К примеру разное время выполнения с 3g и wifi.

Первое что приходит добавить задержку, если через секунду после старта запрос не выполнен отображать прогресс. Но будет опять мигать если запрос займет две секунды итд..

Возможно есть решения?

Comment: Может добавить задержку наоборот после загрузки, если она прошла быстро - пусть повисит полный прогресс, можно приукрасить анимацией плавного исчезновения. Или вообще не показывать прогресс, если объём передаваемых данных не большой.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь возможно лишь компромисное решение. Заранее узнавать скорость интернета, размер загружаемого etc - путь в никуда, ибо всё это может постоянно и непредсказуемо меняться.

Можно, разве что, показывать прогресс с анимацией появления из прозрачности. Например, в течении секунды от 0 до 1. Может так будет лучше выглядеть.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, установите время показа выполнения загрузки по умолчанию. Например, в одну секунду. Если загрузка мгновенная, будет показана загрузка в течении этой одной секунды. Если более продолжительная, то по условиям загрузки.